# how to get javascript replace function to match each occurence and not just the outer occurence

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Given the following text:

```
This <em>is</em> just <em>example</em> text.
```

I want to replace the `<em>...</em>` with `\i...\i` so I tried the replace method this way.

```
replace( /<em>(.+)<\/em>/, "\\i$1\\i" )
```

But the resulting text is:

```
This \iis</em> just <em>example\i text.
```

As you can see, it replaced the outer match but left the `"</em> just <em>"` in the middle untouched.  I want it to replace each occurrance of the match so each instance of `<em>...</em>` gets replace with `\i...\i`.

Answer (score 4):

What is we work with greediness using `?`:

```
str.replace(/<em>(.+?)<\/em>/g, "\\i$1\\i");

// >> "This \iis\i just \iexample\i text."
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick.  Now the resulting text is "This \iis\i just \iexample\i text." as it should be.  Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"This <em>is</em> just <em>example</em> text.".replace(/<\/?em>/gi, "\\i");
```

Explain:

```
/<\/?em>/gi
```

`/gi` global and ignore case (accept "em", "Em", "eM", "EM", you get it)

`\/?` with or without /

Comment: This will also replace unpaired tags -- though I don't know whether the op cares

Comment: Yes, but he want to replace any <em> or </em>, that's not the idea? if you have a unclosed tag, will create a \i unclosed... Not a real problem...